# Inherit from Variable Instead of Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently writing a Rails engine, and I wanted to make its `ApplicationController` descend from the controller specified in the engine's config.

For example, I have in `lib/my_engine.rb` the following:

```
module MyEngine
  mattr_accessor :authenticated_controller

  class << self
    def authenticated_controller
      @@authenticated_controller.constantize
    end  
  end
end
```

In `app/controllers/my_engine/application_controller.rb`, I have:

```
class MyEngine::ApplicationController < MyEngine.authenticated_controller

  #some code

end
```

And in my app's initializer, I set `MyEngine.authenticated_controller = 'AuthenticatedController'`.

This allows me to keep my engine mostly ignorant of the authentication engine, as now all my engine requires is some controller, `AuthenticatedController` in this case, to provide a method with `current_user`.  I used [this blog post](http://ryanbigg.com/2012/03/engines-and-authentication/) for inspiration.

It all seems to work just fine, but I am using RubyMine to develop, and it complains about using a variable instead of a constant in the class definition.  It raises the question of whether this is a good idea or not.

So, is this approach okay?  Are there some gotchas that I am not seeing?  And are there any alternatives to this method?

Comment: Sems fine to me.  RubyMine isn't being considerate of the fact that your project is a Rails engine.  Hence, false warnings are to be expected.

Comment: The warning is more general than that.  Even outside of the context of a Rails app, I see the error.  The exact RubyMine error is `class/module name must be CONSTANT`.

Comment: But thanks for the reassurance that this is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely okay—so long as the variable contains a Class instance when this code runs (which would give a TypeError: “superclass must be a Class”).

Ruby only gives this error when you have a non-constant named class/module, e.g.:

```
class c; end
module m; end
```

as opposed to

```
class C; end
module M; end
```

So either you have this issue elsewhere (unlikely if everything is working as this is an error, not a warning), or RubyMine is incorrectly giving you the error for some reason. Ruby gives no warnings for what you have.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like I should file a bug report for RubyMine.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew points out this is fine in Ruby, and the warning is a problem with RubyMine. One possible approach to work-around the warning and still get the same ruby semantics is to use [`Class::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-c-new) instead of the `class` keyword to define your class:

```
MyEngine::ApplicationController = Class.new(MyEngine.authenticated_controller) do
  #some code
end
```